# Tensorboard v1.0 - Histogram tab interpretation

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, tensorboard

I am learning to visualize tensor via tensorboard, however, I don't know how to interpret chart in Histogram tab. I used below code to visualize:

```
sess = tf.Session()
tf.summary.histogram('test', tf.constant([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]))
summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('../tmp/train', sess.graph)
for i in range(10):
    sum = sess.run(summary)
    train_writer.add_summary(sum, i)
```

I got this chart from tensorboard:

*Histogram mode: offset*
[image]

*Histogram mode: overlay*
[image]

I know the x-axis is the value, y-axis is time step, what I don't know is the value of z-axis. According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5381) issue,

> It's a normalized density. I wouldn't describe it as a probability density,
>   although I think calling it one would be justifiable.

Can anyone explain more (i.e. how the density is calculated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot here shows approximately what it should have shown. Spikes at the values `1, 2, 3, 4`. The biggest spike is at the value 4, the smallest at 3. You see such a strange results because you selected to see the distribution of the output which is hard to visualize as a distribution (the same way as it would not be impressive to look at the circle in 3-d program).

Plot the actual distribution and it will be easier to understand. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

v = np.random.normal(loc=5,  scale=3.0, size=100000)
a = tf.constant(v)
s = tf.summary.histogram('normal', a)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    for i in xrange(10):
        summary = sess.run(merged)
        writer.add_summary(summary, i)

    writer.close()
```

Here you see the normal distribution with mean 5 and std=3.
[image]

Now 10 stacked histograms starting from 0 to 9 are coming from your loop. They are all the same because there is nothing going on with the value `a`. In real work you will see the histogram of your tensors that evolve after each time of the training.

Regarding your image, I assume they smoothen the output and this is why you see such results.

Comment: Thanks. What I am really curious about is how tensorboard generated the "weird" chart for the tensor whose size is small. I think you are right, smoothen the output can be the reason. Maybe I can take some time to dive into the code.

Comment: @Yon would be nice. Please comment or write your own answer when you find it out.